# Finding object being clicked in a set of overlapped objects

Tags: paperjs

There is a circle at the intersection of two lines. How can I figure out if the mouse is clicked on top of circle, line 1, line 2, or somewhere else?

I have used if-then-else ladder to test object.hitTest within view.onClick function. I am testing for lines first and then circle.

[sketch link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/rZPBa4MwFMb/lUcutVCkCrtYdup1h8EGOzQ92PicwTQZ8bVllP7vM2qNXW23wQ5C8r58X355iUem0y2yhL2USKJgMyZM5uac9qmF7eeT1BjBI2g8wHNKRegKwZFbrjlxyq3ZJrCCh/ms/mA9OwtkXDm6qldkTYlLo4xNYLJRqSgn38Q3mVGRQDRvy6fpohk0Ew8V/wx1vfuAKpr/DxYNwZbSCoVDsrbi2QRqQjtOZ9NM7iq3xQ0ui5mnyqVSQ2GsWxIPodFLJUVZQ+U7LUgaHeC+pphCD+XglbvoV6yoXthde1hIcpV2ffhhZO1a9CcxujIKQ2Xeg97s5XNmfJEZ/y0zvs4UTUP70La/v0/1dq/LfHAA3xVOqUJLAWeOHCIQro+YceatJ0BVIXQJ8f2E+H7CAG0sontbtyPGPO3iRj8UaPHC1r2Y+qffWEzLpmsVS1br0xc=)

When I click at circle anywhere within overlapping area with lines, then all the three hitTest return HitResult. What can I do so that only circle hitTest passes through when I click anywhere on the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but you can hit test all items at once by calling `project.hitTest()`.
Only the topmost item will match.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/rZJNi4MwEIb/yuBFyxbRQi/KnrzuYWEX9tD2kMYRs8akjGnLUvrfN7F+9YPdSwMiefLOzBP05ClWo5d4HxUaXnpzj+vc7Q+MoP55EwpjeAWFR3hnpgwdCE5rWiuwqyBdJ7BaRnNYRpt5j422ML6ljSFdYaalpgT8rWS88m8Ov0RuygTiaODOzqY7E9/h8yx1L/eMkot/Je98Rss4eqrm4rFmJohLnHpeyGjKURmkR67EcrFvrkZeexLmo2UhpHx4MGheJt95CjyGWmVS8Mp6FnvFjdAqwIMVm8Hg6e5TCvOJjbGxHelv5CbsyCUd7rSwNWlfIgoIusCkkVtMIpnAb4diDlqBMGg/mA8v/ZDQkdDJjw3PgLLBP1u5wLFEQn9S1l45tf/5lpBVrWXjJavN+Rc=) demonstrating the solution.

```
var myLine1 = new Path.Line({
    from: [50, 50],
    to: [150, 50],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    name: 'myLine1'
});

var myLine2 = new Path.Line({
    from: [150, 50],
    to: [150, 100],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    name: 'myLine2'
});

var myCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: [150, 50],
    radius: 10,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red',
    name: 'myCircle'
});

view.onClick = function(event) {
    var hitTest = project.hitTest(event.point);
    if (hitTest) {
        alert('Clicked on item: ' + hitTest.item.name);
    } else {
        alert('Clicked elsewhere');
    }
};
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thanks!